# Linq skip is skipping the wrong results?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using a linq statement to get my company reviews, but it's skipping the wrong results.

If i pass it currentPage = 1 it gets the right results, if i pass it currentPage 2 it does it wrong. The amount of reviews per page is 10. The GUID id is also passed on correctly.

```
public IList<SupplierReview> GetAmount(int pageAmount, int currentPage, Guid companyId)
    {
        var total = _context.SupplierReview.Count();
        var skipAmount = pageAmount * (currentPage - 1);
        if (skipAmount < total)
        {
            if (pageAmount < (total - skipAmount))
            {
                //return the page amount of reviews

                return _context.SupplierReview
                    .Where(x => x.Company.Id == companyId)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ReviewDate)
                    .Skip(skipAmount)
                    .Take(pageAmount)
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                //if the left amount is less than the pageAmount, 
                //then only the leftovers should get taken

                return _context.SupplierReview
                    .Where(x => x.Company.Id == companyId)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ReviewDate)
                    .Skip(skipAmount)
                    .Take(total - skipAmount)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
        //if nothings left, return null
        return null;
    }
```

The mistake is probably silly, but I can't seem to see it... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The second call to `OrderBy` (in each query) should be `ThenBy` instead? The first `OrderBy` is being thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to specify bigger number than (actual)collection count to both `Skip` & `Take` extension methods, in this case you get an empty collection.

That means we can refine the code as shown below.

```
 return _context.SupplierReview
                    .Where(x => x.Company.Id == companyId)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ReviewDate)
                    .Skip(pageAmount * currentPage) //use currentPage + 1 if index assumed to start with 1
                    .Take(pageAmount)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Right, tested it out and you are correct! seems to work just fine... However, i still get the wrong results in my trails. I have 11 reviews, and when i open page 2 i get result 1 from page 1?

Comment: Unless the collection get modified in between it should return correct results, are you getting an additional row or one row that was already shown as part of page1?

Comment: If possible attach screenshots, that helps resolving the problem.

Comment: Rebuilding the whole solution fixed it, guess it wasn't getting processed, thanks again for the help, the code you gave me improved my code!

Answer (score 2):

My first thought about skipping too many pages was incorrect. It looks like you are mixing up the total count:

`var total = _context.SupplierReview.Count();`

then the count which match your company.ID:

`Where(x => x.Company.Id == companyId)`

I feel like the `total` calculation should include this `Where`? Look at your `else` condition. If you `.Take(total - skipAmount)`, and total was calculated without regard to your company ID, you will end up trying to take too many, potentially a non-existent amount.

Comment: if page is 5, I'm skipping 40 reviews

Comment: because page 1 has 1-10
page 2 has 11-20

Comment: Edited my answer. Found something that could be problematic.

Comment: Ow yeah right i def. need to add a where to the total count! But it still wouldn't fix the problem of not getting the right reviews though...

Comment: It's working now, thanks a lot for the comments! It helped me improve my code!